# Question about the closure of a set

Tags: general-topology

How to find $\overline{A}$, where $A=\lbrace (-1)^n(1+\frac1n), n\in \mathbb{N}^*\rbrace$

Please give me the steps to do in order to find $\overline{A}$

Thank you

Comment: You need to add the limit points, ie, you need to add $\lim_{n \to \infty} (-1)^n (1+ \dfrac{1}{n})$

Comment: @Luis: That sequence does not have a limit.

Comment: Oh! You are right. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

$$
A=B+C
$$
where
$$
B=\lbrace (1+\frac1{2n}), n\in \mathbb{N}^*\rbrace \\
C=\lbrace -(1+\frac1{2n+1}), n\in \mathbb{N}^*\rbrace
$$
since $B$ and $C$ are contained in disjoint open sets we have:
$$
\overline{A} = \overline{B} \cup \overline{C}
$$
does this help?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Firstly, illustrate this set by drawing the points on the real line on a piece of paper. Then denote $x_{n}=(-1)^{n}(1+\frac{1}{n})$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and consider the two subsequences $(x_{2n})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ and $(x_{2n+1})_{n=1}^{\infty}$ separately and see if you can use them to find the limit points of $A$.